# Creating Columns for Summed Answers

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So I'm trying to move my row info into the column - I haven't used a `Pivot` before and tried using it now but clearly I'm doing something wrong -.-;

Here is my original Query

```
(Select
    CASE WHEN ee.ExpenseTypeID=1 THEN Sum(Amount)
    WHEN ee.ExpenseTypeID=2 THEN Sum(Amount)
    WHEN ee.ExpenseTypeID=3 THEN Sum(Amount)
    WHEN ee.ExpenseTypeID=4 THEN Sum(Amount) END as Amount,
    et.ExpenseDescription,
    ee.UserID
    From ExpensesEntries ee, ExpenseTypes et
    Where ee.ExpenseTypeID=et.ExpenseTypeID
    Group By ee.ExpenseTypeID, et.ExpenseDescription, ee.UserID
    Order By UserID) b
```

Which produces something like this

```
Amount    | ExpenseDescription | UserID
----------------------------------------
156.00    | Upload             | 123
----------------------------------------
23.00     | Parking            | 123
----------------------------------------
15.37     | Other              | 123
----------------------------------------
112.00    | Other              | 456
----------------------------------------
28.50     | Parking            | 456
----------------------------------------
```

What I would like to do

```
UserID | Upload | Parking | Other 
----------------------------------
123    | 156.00 | 23.00   | 15.37
----------------------------------
456    | NULL   | 28.50   | 112.00
```

I tried doing this - which is the equivalent of slapping on a `Pivot` but with the Cases in my original select - I'm not sure if I need to get rid of them entirely and add it into `Pivot` ?

```
Select 
    CASE WHEN ee.ExpenseTypeID=1 THEN Sum(Amount)
    WHEN ee.ExpenseTypeID=2 THEN Sum(Amount)
    WHEN ee.ExpenseTypeID=3 THEN Sum(Amount)
    WHEN ee.ExpenseTypeID=4 THEN Sum(Amount) END as Amount,
    et.ExpenseDescription,
    ee.UserID
    From ExpensesEntries ee, ExpenseTypes et
    Where ee.ExpenseTypeID=et.ExpenseTypeID
    Group By ee.ExpenseTypeID, et.ExpenseDescription, ee.UserID
    Order By UserID
    PIVOT
    (Amount
    FOR et.ExpenseDescription IN ('Upload','Other','Parking')
    ) as pvt
```

Comment: Try saying `PIVOT (SUM(Amount) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide details on what each of the `ExpenseTypeId` values relate to but you can do this using an aggregate function with a CASE expression. The CASE expression will check the value of the `ExpenseTypeId` and get a sum of the amount - you will then name the column with the `ExpenseDescription`:

```
select ee.UserId,
    sum(case when ee.ExpenseTypeID=1 then Amount else 0 end) Upload,
    sum(case when ee.ExpenseTypeID=2 then Amount else 0 end) Parking,
    sum(case when ee.ExpenseTypeID=3 then Amount else 0 end) Other
from ExpensesEntries ee
inner join ExpenseTypes et
    on ee.ExpenseTypeID=et.ExpenseTypeID
group by ee.UserId;
```

If you want to use PIVOT, then you would alter your query to something similar to the following.  This uses a join between your 2 tables in a subquery and you return the `UserId`, `ExpenseDescription` and `Amount`.  The PIVOT will sum the amount for each `ExpenseDescription` - this process converts the descriptions to columns:

```
select UserId, Upload, Other, Parking
from
(
    select ee.UserId,
        et.ExpenseDescription 
        Amount
    from ExpensesEntries ee
    inner join ExpenseTypes et
        on ee.ExpenseTypeID=et.ExpenseTypeID
) d
pivot
(
    sum(Amount)
    for ExpenseDescription in (Upload, Other, Parking)
) p;
```

Comment: Had some trouble with the first query - it did what I asked but still had multiple rows for Parking, Other, Daily.  

However the Pivot worked perfectly! Thanks